# How do you create a pointer-based binary tree without using dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation

Some C++ programmers say that dynamic memory allocation is bad and should be avoided whenever possible. I tried making a binary tree data structure without using dynamic memory allocation, and it doesn't work. Here's what I tried:

```
struct BTNode {
    BTNode *left = 0, *right = 0;
    int data;

    BTNode(int d_) { data = d_; }

    void insert(int d_) {
        BTNode n(d_);
        if (d_ <= data)
            if (left == 0) left = &n;
            else left->insert(d_);
        else 
            if (right == 0) right = &n;
            else right->insert(d_);
    }
}
```

And then doing this in main...

```
BTNode root(8);
root.insert(9);
root.insert(10);
cout << root.right->right->data;
```

results in a segfault, because the BTNode containing the data went out of scope a long time ago.

My question is, how is one supposed to structure a pointer-based binary tree like this without the use of `new` and `delete`?

Comment: Use values instead of pointers

Comment: You can create an array of `BTNode` with sufficient elements and use it as memory pool, taking nodes from the array.

Comment: You could create a `std::vector<BTNode>` to hold all the nodes. I personally don't think that is necessary. I would simply do `auto newNode = new BTNode(8);` and then set the appropriate pointers.

Comment: What you were advised was probably to avoid managing `new` and `delete` yourself. There's actually nothing wrong with [dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. You are not obliged to follow what 'some C++programmers think'.

Comment: Actually dynamic memory allocation is nothing to be afraid of. Just make sure to use RAII to release your memory correctly. I'd only try to avoid dynamic allocation, when performance is a big issue. Yet I only rarely need it.

Comment: Also, don't use 0 for invalid pointers. Use `nullptr`.

Comment: @bluefog nullptr is new in C++11. Not everyone is using C++11 yet. For older versions, 0 is needed.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: you pretty much can't.

The only possible way is for the entire tree to be in either automatic, or global scope, and constructed manually:

```
BTNode root;
BTNode left, right;

root.left=&left;
root.right=&right;
```

But, either the whole thing gets destroyed, when the automatic scope is left, or you now have a bunch of ugly globals.

There's nothing wrong with dynamic scope, and dynamic memory allocation; provided that it's used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all your nodes in a single  `std::array<>`. They can freely point to each other an when you release your array, all your nodes are safely released as well. You just have to make sure to know which elements in your array have already been used.

Any way, please only implement your own trees and similar containers for educational reasons, or if you have very, very, very good reasons not to use the ones provided by the standard library. In the latter case, mimic the standard interface as closely as possible in order to enable standard algorithms, range based for-loops, and easily understandable code for other C++ developers.

Answer (score 0):

The insert method is allocating the BTNode object on the stack, that means the object's memory is invalid once the insert function returns.

You could do

```
       BTNode newObj( 9 ) 
       root.insert( newObj );
```

You would also have to modify the insert method to

```
       void insert(BTNode &node) { ...
```

in this case newObj object remains in scope until you leave your main function.
Even better you can make it of static scope, then it will be around for the duration of the program.